# Here is my edit reducer .It works fine but i want to use object.assign method

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is my reducer in which when todo id matches with the id of payload in action it changes the value but i want to use object.assign metod .

```
case EDIT_TODO:

  return state.map(todo => {
    if(todo.id === action.payload.id){
        return {
          ...todo,
         text: action.payload.text
        }
      }
      return todo;
    });
```

Comment: What makes you think your state is mutating ?

Comment: it directly apply changes to 'text'

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you aren't mutating the state since `Map` returns a new array and also for the id that matches, you are closing the object and updating it.

Only thing is that the other todo object still holds the same reference but that is fine.

And even if `text` is an object you currently are assigning a new reference to it and if you want to merge you can use the spread syntax but from what it seems by your naming convention `text` seems to be a `string` which is javascript is `Immutable`

```
case EDIT_TODO:

  return state.map(todo => {
    if(todo.id === action.payload.id){
        return {
          ...todo,
         text: action.payload.text
        }
      }
      return todo;
    });
```

Comment: this.state = {
          isediting: false,
          text: '',
          itemToEdit:'',
         
        };

Comment: @user9746311 text is a string in your case, so you don't need spread syntax, string assignment by default is immutable in javascript

Comment: ok i understand it but if  i want to use object.assign method how can i use i want to learn

Comment: Just like you did for todo.

Answer (score 0):

First, as the other response noted, you are not mutating anything (you are returning a new object) with spread syntax.

If you want to achieve the same thing with `Object.assign`, you can do:

```
case EDIT_TODO:
      return state.map(todo => {
        if(todo.id === action.payload.id){
            return Object.assign({}, todo, text)
          }
          return todo;
        });
```

This line:

```
        return Object.assign({}, todo, text)
```

Says "create a new empty object (first parameter) and assign the following properties to that empty object: todo, text (rest of parameters)"